# Python: No module named database

Tags: python, module, python-import

I have looked at so many questions exactly like this but none of the solutions work its infuriating.

I want to call methods in a class in python that exist in a different module.

I have added **init**.py to each directory.

Structure:

- server

  - database

    - __init.py
    - mongo.py
  - rabbit

    - _init_py
    - worker.py

In worker.py I import mongo as such:

`from database import mongo`

I then get the error 'No module named 'database' at runtime.

Please somebody explain, thanks!

Comment: Do you have a database.py file somewhere? What is `database`?

Comment: It is The module

Comment: `from database.mongo import [your class]` or `import database.mongo`. You need to import from a `py` file, not a directory.

Comment: I need to use the methods in that class however. How do I then access the methods

Comment: In order for that import to work, `.../server` would have to be in your `PYTHONPATH` environment setting, or you'd have to manually add it to `sys.path` inside the code.

Comment: `import database.mongo as mongo`.

Comment: import database.mongo as mongo did not work

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse If the error is "No module named 'database'", I don't see how `import database.mongo as mongo` could possibly work.  It can't _find_ the `database` module!

Comment: I just really thought it would be easy to do this. I imagine this question must seem so stupid to others but from a Java background it just seems crazy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
from database import mongo
```

Comment: Seems crazy that this is the only solution but fair enough haha